# Apache Drill REST API not working on top of Plain Authentication

Tags: apache-drill

We have install apache drill 1.10 and have implemented "Plain Authentication".After applying authentication mechanism,not able to create storage plugin through REST API.But it was working before we had applied authentication.
here we are trying to create storage plugin through REST api call..

```
    Please help me how can we execute REST by using some user credential.
    http://172.18.128.12:8047/storage/hdfs_test.json 
    {
    "name": "hdfs_test",
    "config": 
    {
    "type" : "file",
    "enabled" : true,
    "connection" : "hdfs://<IP>:8020/",
    "workspaces" : {
    "root" : {
    "location" : "/tmp",
    "writable" : true,
    "defaultInputFormat" : null
    }
    },
    "formats" : {
    "json" : {
    "type" : "json"
    }
    }
    }
    } 

    below is the error
    Invalid username/password credentials.
```

Please help us,if someone has already faced this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix the 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. Replace 'https' with 'http' if https is not enabled.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -k -c cookies.txt -s -d "j_username=<USER-NAME>" -d "j_password=<PASSWORD>" https://localhost:8047/j_security_check
```

Below is a sample command for enabling hive storage plugin.Modify parameter values according to your environment.

```
curl -k -b cookies.txt -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"hive", "config": {"type": "hive", "enabled": true, "configProps" : { "hive.metastore.uris" : "thrift://lab-node1:9083", "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" : "jdbc:mysql://lab-node1:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true", "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" : "/user/hive/warehouse",  "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "true", "hive.server2.enable.doAs": "true" } }}' https://localhost:8047/storage/hive_test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example for querying a JSON file through the Drill REST API using curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -k -c cookies.txt -s -d "j_username=<USER-NAME>" -d "j_password=<PASSWORD>" https://localhost:8047/j_security_check 

curl -k -b cookies.txt -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "SELECT * FROM dfs.`/tmp/data.json` limit 2"}' https://localhost:8047/query.json
```